# why does stitching_detailed.py and stitching_detailed.cpp produce such different results?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, sample

Im trying to understand why stitching_detailed.py and stitching_detailed.cpp have such differnt results when their code base in logic is very similar.

these are the links to both code bases

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/stitching_detailed.py
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp

the question is, how and where should i edit stitching_detailed.py to have it produce as good quality stitching as stitching_detailed.cpp?

```
    # """calculate corner and size of time step"""
corners = []
sizes = []
for i in range(len(img_names)):
    cameras[i].focal *= 0.9999/work_scale
    cameras[i].ppx *= 1/work_scale
    cameras[i].ppy *= 1/work_scale
    sz = (full_img_sizes[i][0] * 1, full_img_sizes[i][1] * 1)
    K = cameras[i].K().astype(np.float32)
    roi = warper.warpRoi(sz, K, cameras[i].R)
    corners.append(roi[0:2])
    sizes.append(roi[2:4])

dst_sz = cv2.detail.resultRoi(corners=corners, sizes=sizes)
blender.prepare(dst_sz)

"""Panorama construction step"""
# https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp#L725 ?
for idx, name in enumerate(img_names):
    corner, image_warped = warper.warp(name, cameras[idx].K().astype(np.float32), cameras[idx].R, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT)
    p, mask_warped = warper.warp(255 * np.ones((name.shape[0], name.shape[1]), np.uint8), cameras[idx].K().astype(np.float32), cameras[idx].R, cv2.INTER_NEAREST, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    compensator.apply(idx, corners[idx], image_warped, mask_warped)
    mask_warped = cv2.bitwise_and(cv2.resize(cv2.dilate(masks_warped[idx], None), (mask_warped.shape[1], mask_warped.shape[0]), 0, 0, cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT), mask_warped)
    blender.feed(cv2.UMat(image_warped.astype(np.int16)), mask_warped, corners[idx])

result, result_mask = blender.blend(None, None)
dst = cv2.normalize(src=result, dst=None, alpha=255., norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

My hypothesis is that pythons "blender" functions differently the c++ blender. this is a snippet of code that ive refractored to narrow down my problem to, i think.

Comment: you can always use the cpp interface even while inside python https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/07/18/python-using-c-cpp-libraries-ctypes/

Comment: Please provide a [mre] within the question itself without relying on external links

Comment: the reason im trying to replicate c++ stitching into python is because im more familiar with python to incorporate GPU code with cv2.cuda_GpuMat,arrayfire python, or Pycuda to utilize GPU. other wise, i might as well learn c++ cuda and adapt composePanorama to process with cv::GpuMat arrays which will take a long time. c++ composePanorama takes too long to stitch 4K(3140x2160p) together.